# SSIS - Set multiple package variables from query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am working on an SSIS 2010 package that makes use of multiple package variables that I want to populate with the results of a SQL query.  We have an app settings table that is set up as such:

```
[ID]     [settingName]     [settingValue]
 1           appName           test app
 2         scheduled             yes
```

Within the package, I have variables set up for appName and scheduled but I'm having a hard time figuring out the best way to load them from the database.  The query is running successfully, just a simple select statement, but I'm not sure what to do next.  I've found suggestions saying I should parse it out in a script task but it seems like there should be a much easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Your query needs to return a single row that contains the values for each variable in separate columns:
[image]

Then map the result set columns to your variables:
[image]

In short, you need to pivot your query.

Edit: Like this. (minus the table variable; use your actual table)

```
declare @pivot table (settingname varchar(20), settingvalue varchar(20))
insert into @pivot
values
('appname','test app'),
('scheduled','yes')

SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT settingname, settingvalue from @pivot
) as source
pivot
(
 max(settingvalue)
 for settingname in ([appname],[scheduled])
)
as pvt
```

Comment: That makes sense, not to be a help vampire but could you show me how to pivot the query?

Comment: No worries, though I am terrible at pivoting.  (I wrote a dynamic SP just so I wouldn't have to do it any more)